# Whats wrong in this asp.net code? Textbox value doesnt set

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count > 100) 
    {
        StringBuilder javascript = new StringBuilder();
        javascript.Append(" <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
        javascript.Append(" var tmp = confirm(\"No:Of Records exceeds 1000.Please    confirm you want to continue\");");
        javascript.Append("if (tmp)");
        javascript.Append("{document.getElementById(\"    <%=TextBox1.ClientID%>\").value=\"1\"; alert(document.getElementById(\"<%=TextBox1.ClientID     %>\").value);}");


        javascript.Append(" </script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "recordscript", javascript.ToString(), false);

        return;
    }
}
```

Here I want to set the value of the textbox by clicking the button event and oly that condition is true.So I cant call that function from source.actually that function gets called but the textbox value doesnt set..I really dont understand where is the problem..

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if(count>100) 
{
        StringBuilder javascript = new StringBuilder();
        javascript.Append(" <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
        javascript.Append(" var tmp = confirm(\"No:Of Records exceeds 1000.Please    confirm you want to continue\");");
        javascript.Append("if (tmp)");
        javascript.Append("{document.getElementById('" + TextBox1.ClientID + "').value=\"1\"; alert(document.getElementById('" + TextBox1.ClientID+ "').value);}");


        javascript.Append(" </script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "recordscript", javascript.ToString(), false);

        return;
    }
}
}
```

You need to concatenate the TextBox1.ClientID with your javascript string. The code you have will get rendered to the page as is, look at the output of your rendered page with view source, you will see the string '<%= TextBox1.ClientID =%>' not the expected ID. Keep in mind that the inline display expression <%= =%> is equivalent to a server Response.Write().

Comment: You missed the quotes between `TextBox1.ClientID`